# VBA to insert picture fails

Tags: image, insert, dialog

I am recently facing an error when running the below dialog while computer is not connected to the internet:
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
When there is internet connection, the insert picture dialog pops up.
When there is no connection, the dialog window is simply empty - white.

I need to have the dialog working when computer is offline.

Any solution please?

Thanks
PanosGR

Trying to click on a picture that runs Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show.